# How to convert list<String> into String in Dart without iteration?

Tags: string, list, dart

Is there a method in Dart like the `String.join()` method in Java & c#?

**input:**

```
nums: ["20",  "3005",  "2"]
```

**output:**

```
nums = "2030052"
```

Answer (score 184):

`join` is a method of the List class, rather than String:

```
List<String> yourList = ["20", "3005", "2"];

// To test that the above the above
yourList.join() == '2030052';     // true
yourList.join(',') == '20,3005,2'; // true, with "," delimiter
```

Comment: `yourList.join()`?

Comment: @zerkms yes this do the job and return a String

Comment: @MohamedDernoun it was a comment to point out to the typo Mike made which they fixed.

Answer (score 7):

This might not be the best solution, but you can reduce a collection to a single value by iteratively combining elements of the collection using the **reduce** method in Dart Lists.

```
String nums = numsList.reduce((value, element) => value + ',' + element);
```

You have to remember that, the iterable must have at least one element. If it has only one element, that element is returned.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had to convert into flat string. So this is the way I found;

> ```
> List<String> tags = ["#heyy", "@newday", "#newpp"];
>
>     
> print(tags.join(' ')); // "#heyy @newday #newpp"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> onlyString=[];
onlyString.add("Flutter");
for(int i=0; i < onlyString.length; i++){
print(onlyString[i].toString());}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.